# What's [NSException initWithCoder:]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, ios8, crash

In my crash log, I see [NSException initWithCoder:] at the top of the crashed stack trace.  What's NSException initWithCoder? Why would NSException have this method?  Note: I am not interested in knowing the cause of the crash, but why NSException's initWithCoder appears here and what it's doing.

Example crash logs:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         6874214720 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        6875041528 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              6873639800 abort + 140
3  Dringend                       4298949820 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4299310268
4  libc++abi.dylib                6854520644 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
5  libc++abi.dylib                6854519568 __cxa_rethrow + 144
6  Dringend                       4298949752 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4299310200
7  libc++abi.dylib                6854520644 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
8  libc++abi.dylib                6854518876 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 134
9  libobjc.A.dylib                6864339092 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 330
10 CoreFoundation                 6515019408 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 118
11 CoreFoundation                 6513992388 -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 140
12  <…>                           4298521360 -[ViewController <…>] (<…>:1633)
```

Comment: `initWithCoder` is part of the NSCoding protocol that allows object serialization  and deserialization. Why would NSException not have this method?

Comment: What is NSException doing with its initWithCoder right before the crash?

Comment: Post the full crash log

Comment: Why do you need the full crash log? [NSException initCoder:] happens on many types of crashes.

Comment: I don't know. I don't think your question makes any sense but if you're going to ask about something you see in your crash log you should at least include the crash log.

Comment: "What is NSException doing with its initWithCoder right before the crash?" ... It would appear that your view controller called `substringWithRange` and that it threw an exception (which caused `NSException` to be instantiated), which lead to your crash.

Comment: @Rob Thanks - not interested in knoowing about the cause of the crash, but why NSException initWithCoder appears here.